# Create node via URL parameters to different drupal site

Tags: 7, rules, emails, services

I am looking for a way to create a node via just a URL. I know the prepopulate module and similar can auto populate a form for a user to submit, but I would like to avoid the form altogether.

After a node on Site A expires I would like to allow users to add information about the expired node into Site B via email. So Site A will send out an email like:

> "Your listing has expired. Did you sell your product? If so, you can add that information to SITE B and view what others have paid for it. Just click the link below:
>
> http://siteb.com/field_location/Provo,Utah/field_category/Antiques/field_price/56.76>/etc..."

When the user clicks on the link, it will create a node with those values.

My main concern is spam prevention and validation.

Is there any module that would help with this? Prepopulate, Rules Link (Rules), Services, etc...

It doesn't have to be complex. It's only for one content type with only a few fields.

Thanks

Comment: When selecting a solution for this be very conscious of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Comment: Thank you for your input. Which is why I am concerned about validation. Maybe add a key field similar to cron_key to verify the user is able to do this.

Comment: Actually, creating a RSS feed with Views on SITEA and using Feeds on SITEB might be the safest way to implement this. However, without Flags or some other method, users would be unable to approve/deny the transfer.

Comment: According to me you just need to create a url (if it is fixed) in your custom module like $items['abc/%/%/%...']. and when you hit this url, you need to call a custom function in which you create a node programmatically.

Comment: I'm assuming you'd require the user to auth on site B? As @harsh says, just create a wildcard URL via hook_menu in a custom module on site B and pass the path args to your callback function. I'm not sure why your URL has field_names in it, you can omit those - long links can be problematic in mail clients. I'm assuming you'd need some kind of UUID in there too, as syncing data across sites would require it. You may have to check_plain() your args in your callback. If all that's too complicated, look at the feeds module.

Comment: depending on your set up, you could force site B to use the field values from the db of Site A, then just use a boolean verification field which B would read and know to use that node, ignoring the others. This keeps the transfer of information to nothing and is essentially using multiple sites with a shared db (or part of it at least) which Drupal is designed to handle securely

Comment: @harsh, What would be a good way to handle auth? Site A would be a user based site and Site B is basically just a data aggregator that anonymizes the data from Site A. Site B doesn't need user access/permissions. I also don't want to share DB tables between the two sites.

So what about hard-coding a key in a hook_menu callback function similar to cron_key? Then just have the function check to see if the key matches? Sure it's simple, but is it a safe way to handle basic auth before I use _sanitize and _validate functions to test the URL arguments before importing them into a node.

Comment: yes, may be you have to write the custom validation before you do import, if all the arguments are matching to your desired parameters.